# Задание по информатике

Tags: python, информатика

Вот задача и миниатюра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n = 0
for i in range(int(input())):
    n += input()=='красный'
print(n)
```

в чем ошибка?

Comment: Ну Python не особо дружит с русскими буквами, можете попробовать изменить их на английские, может помочь. Плюс к тому вы не делаете проверку на жёлтый цвет. А ещё у вас к числу прибавляется `boolean`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 добавлять `boolean` не страшно, добавится 0 или 1.

Comment: @DiMithras не понял?? А так можно было что-ли???

Comment: @ΝNL993 да. Скажу больше, `True + True` будет 2.

Comment: В Питоне в арифметике False приводится к нулю, True - к единице. Все этим пользуются. Авторы языка считают это ошибкой в дизайне (и так оно и есть) но ничего исправить не могут. Потому что все этим пользуются.

Comment: В какой кодировке исходный код? Вы на Windows работаете? Убедитесь что кодировка файла UTF-8, не cp1251 (или cp866 :).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy мдам... ещё больше причин не учить Python... Кодировка у меня всегда `UTF-8`, но во всех редакторах кода и т.п. (предназначенных для Python, в том числе и онлайн песочниц) выводится ошибка при использовании русских.

Comment: @ΝNL993 вот в Python в отличие от других языков (например C/C++ под windows) проблем с кириллицей практически нет. Настраиваете редактор кода, чтобы было UTF-8  в приоритете, и все. Что там за ошибки были в песочницах тоже нужно смотреть, может вы через python 2 запускали, там для кириллицы в любой кодировке нужно еще в начале файла фактическую кодировку указать.

Comment: @insolor окей теперь это всё объясняет, спасибо большое.

Comment: В условии сказано "сколько *раз* светофор показывал красный сигнал". Не минут, а раз.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то так:

```
n = 0

for i in range(int(input())):
    if input().lower() == 'красный':
        n += 1

print(n)
```